# Cannot read NTAG203 with MFRC522

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I tried regular RFID tags and It works but when I tried NTAG203 it won't detect.

P.S. I used the code "dump_data" example of MFRC library.

Comment: what are `regular RFID tags`? MFRC522 reads NFC tags - "RFID" tags include non NFC tags

Comment: @JaromandaX Mifare 1k Card is what i referred to. I could easily read that card but not a NTAG203 sticker